# pattern property of <input> and regex to match against doesn't work

Tags: regex, input

I have an input element of the type text that I wish to allow only input that has a . between every other character.
I'm a bit obsessive about data integrity and wish to build in as many failsaves as I can, starting with the users.

The form is set up to receive input like this:

```
Firstname:     |John____________________|
First Letters: |J.W.H.__________________|
Lastname:      |Baker___________________|
```

I have the following regexp that works beautifully normally, but won't work in the pattern field of the form.

```
/.{1}\./g
```

This is the form that I am using to match against, but it won't let me pass if I fill in the correct pattern.

```
<input type="text" name="firstletters" pattern="/.{1}\./g" title="First name letters with a . in between each letter.">
```

Anyone have a solution?
The length of the string can vary depending how many first names the person being added to the database.

Comment: Could you explain to me *why* it won't work?  I'm not sure I understand, but I'd like to help.

Comment: Well, it doesn't allow a pattern like `j.h.w` to pass or `J.H.W.` or `A.B.C.` whilst it should allow that to pass. Pattterns like `J.HW` should fail and `J.H.W` should also fail

Comment: The pattern seems fine. In your HTML example you left the pattern out `pattern=""` - is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use groups with ^(start of string),$(end of string)

```
^(.\.)+$
```

Comment: So was this an issue with the ^ and $ symbols, or the fact that you added the "one or more" + sign?  I imagine it was the latter as including ^ and $ should only limit matches, not accept more, right?

Comment: @BlackVegetable `^` and `$` would match **completely** not **partially**..`+` is also required becuz there can be 1 to many occurrences of `.\.`

Comment: Alright, thanks for clearing that up.  The proper time to use ^ and $ sometimes eludes me.  +1